# c++ manipulators, is it possible to combine setprecision manip with setfill manip?

Tags: c++

can i use setprecision with setfil...i tried it but somethings seems wrong

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout  << setprecision(10) << setfill('*');
cout << 123;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What output do you get? What output did you expect? And *what* "seems wrong"?

Comment: What do you expect [`setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) to do?

Comment: Did you mean ```setw(x)```?

Answer (score 3):

`setprecision` has nothing to do with `setfill`.

`setprecision` works to set decimal places.

`setfill` works when there is extra places in the column.

To see this clearly, you can add somthing like `setw(15)` to your line like this:

```
int main()
{
cout  << setprecision(10) << setw(15) << setfill('*');
cout << 123;
}
```

Comment: Hehe, hijacking my comment, we are? ;-)

Comment: Sorry @Robert Andrzejuk, did not pay attention to your comment. You can post your comment as answer and I would delete mine.

Comment: Don't need to post another answer :-) Your's looks fine.